# How to transform this XML into HTML using XSLT..?

Tags: xml, xslt

Following is the **XML** piece of code -

```
<Groups>
  <Group i=1>
    <Member t="P.M" dec="Y">ABC</Member>
    <Member t="P.L">PQR</Member>
    <Member t="M">XYZ</Member>
  </Group>
  <Group i=2>
    <Member t="M" dec="Y">ABC</Member>
    <Member t="M">PQR</Member>  
  </Group>
  <Group i=3>
    <Member t="P.L" dec="Y">ABC</Member>
    <Member t="M">PQR</Member>  
    <Member t="M">XYZ</Member>  
  </Group>
  <Group i=4>
    <Member t="M">ABC</Member>
    <Member t="M" dec="Y">PQR</Member>  
  </Group>
  <Group i=5>
    <Member t="M">ABC</Member>
    <Member t="M" dec="Y">PQR</Member>  
    <Member t="M" dec="Y">XYZ</Member>  
  </Group>
  <Group i=6>
    <Member t="M" dec="Y">ABC</Member>
  </Group>

</Groups>
```

Desired HTML output using **XSLT 1.0** -

```
<U>ABC</U>, P.M, PQR, P.L and XYZ, M
<U>ABC</U> and PQR, MM
<U>ABC</U>, P.L, PQR and XYZ, MM
ABC and <U>PQR</U>, MM
ABC, <U>PQR</U> and <U>XYZ</U>, MM
<U>ABC</U>, M
```

Description -

1. Each Node value is appended by its attribute value by comma.
2. If 2 members, then an **and** between the Node and Attribute value. (Ex- `i=2`)
3. If more than 2 members, then a **comma** between first 2 members and
   an **and** between 2 and 3 member (Ex- `i=1 i=3 i=5`)
4. If attribute `dec="Y"` then `<U>..</U>` to that Node Value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a perfectly standard grouping problem. Therefore considerably easier in XSLT 2.0. Use `xsl:for-each-group` in XSLT 2.0; use Muenchian grouping if you're stuck with XSLT 1.0. Read up on grouping techniques and come back here if you are still stuck.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yes this time I will try and come back again with either solution or issues :)